# NERDTreeToggle opens a second tree of parent directory that stays open after toggle (neovim/nerdtree)

Tags: nerdtree, neovim

When I toggle nerdtree it opens a tree of current working dir and a parent dir tree. If I toggle again the parent tree remains. 
I only want the current dir tree to open and close. 
I am using this config file that I found on youtube. https://gist.github.com/benawad/b768f5a5bbd92c8baabd363b7e79786f
Thank you in advance to anyone willing to leave comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably either found a solution already or quit using NERDTree, but if you still happen to be looking for a clue, try to get rid of the part below. I stumbled in that very repo and realised that such part was clashing with manual NERDTree toggling:

```
" Call NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable
" file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! SyncTree()
  if &modifiable && IsNERDTreeOpen() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

" Highlight currently open buffer in NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * call SyncTree()
```

In general, try to debug code by taking relevant parts away and readding them one by one until you figure out the non working bit.